# How to use Group BY with foreach in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I have a stored procedure, and I want to use `GROUP BY` in `FOREACH` statement like this:

```
FOREACH SELECT a.task_code, a.task_name, MAX(a.cand_num)
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.task_code, a.task_name, 0 as cand_num   
                  INTO ll_task_code, ls_task_name, ll_cand_num  
                ...........
                ...........
               ) AS u
         GROUP BY a.task_code, a.task_name
    RETURN ll_task_code, ls_task_name, ll_cand_num WITH RESUME;
END FOREACH;
```

---

but I get a syntax error
in `into ll_task_code, ls_task_name, ll_cand_num`

How to use `GROUP BY` with  `FOREACH`?

Comment: It is odd that when you get an error about "INTO" you assume the problem is with GROUP BY and not the INTO clause.  As the accepted answer correctly points out, the INTO clause must come immediately after the outermost SELECT list and before the outermost FROM clause of the SELECT statement.

Comment: no , i just explain the whole case to be more clear .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `into` outside and try.

```
FOREACH SELECT a.task_code, a.task_name, MAX(a.cand_num)
          INTO ll_task_code, ls_task_name, ll_cand_num  
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.task_code, a.task_name, 0 as cand_num   
                ...........
                ...........
               ) AS u
         GROUP BY a.task_code, a.task_name
    RETURN ll_task_code, ls_task_name, ll_cand_num WITH RESUME;
END FOREACH;
```